# Create Hierarchical ContextMenu dynamically MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

I would like to create dynamically Hierarchical ContextMenu from data in ViewModel.

In ViewMode, I defined ContextMenuAction:

```
public class ContextMenuAction : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public ICommand Action { get; set; }
    public Brush Icon { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ContextMenuAction> SubActions { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ContextMenuAction>();
}
```

In View:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.Actions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<ContextMenu.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate DataType="MenuItem">
        <MenuItem/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>

<ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SubActions}"/>
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Action}"/>
    </Style>
</ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This is result, there no text in context menu.

[image]

I already check output window to check binding, all bindings work, there is no exception.

Please help me to find out the reason, thank in advance!

Comment: You can use "Snoop" program to check the DataContext of the MenuItem at  RunTime and see if the data is what you expect it to be.
Search google for "wpf snoop". 
Its an open source program these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.Actions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ContextMenuAction}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubActions}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Action}"/>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: It worked! I have one more question, in case i would like to add Separator, could you please give me a suggestion.

Comment: Add a separator where? Please ask a new question if you have another issue.